# Multitouch in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, multi-touch

I have a big problem with my 2 created buttons that can move.. They both work but are using the same getX(), get Y() data. How can i make them take differend data when i touch them with differend fingers at the same time?

(one button is for moving next is for shooting)

```
foreverTimer+=delta;
    if(foreverTimer<0.1){if(attackPressed){
        float y=0, x=0, getY=Gdx.input.getY(), getX=Gdx.input.getX();
        if((HEIGHT - getY)>=attackY+attackButton.getHeight()/3||(HEIGHT - getY)<=attackY-attackButton.getHeight()/3||getX>attackX+attackButton.getWidth()/3||getX<attackX-attackButton.getWidth()/3)
        {   
            y=(HEIGHT - getY-attackY); x = getX-attackX;
            Player.shoot(x, y);
        }}
    }else
    if(foreverTimer>=0.1){
//RIGHT HERE I COMMAND TO TAKE NEW X,Y FOR NEXT BUTTON AND TURN OFF OTHER BUTTON BUT THE X AND Y ARE STILL THE SAME
            float getY=Gdx.input.getY(), getX=Gdx.input.getX();
            foreverTimer-=0.1;
            if(movePressed)
            {
                if(getX>moveX+moveButton.getWidth()/3){a=false; d=true;} else if(getX<moveX-moveButton.getWidth()/3){d=false; a=true;}      else{a=false; d=false;}
                if((HEIGHT - getY)>moveY+moveButton.getHeight()/2){s=false; Player.sit=false; spres=false;  w=true; wpres=true;} else if((HEIGHT - getY)<moveY-moveButton.getHeight()/2){s=true; spres=true; w=false; wpres=false;}           else{s=false; Player.sit=false; spres=false; w=false; wpres=false; }  
            }else {wpres=spres=d=a=false;}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
    Gdx.Input.getX(int pointer)
```

and try to iterate from up to some max count of touches (in your example 2) to get all **X** and **Y** coordinates of fingers touching screen. Then just check if any of **(x, y)** is about one of your button.

Please consider also using **Scene2d** and its Actors and ContactListeners. I think it would be very very helpful here in your case.

You can read about it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d